# group by clause taking too much time

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have following table (MYTable)

```
ID    joindate        AnyText  deptid
1     2013/10/10       ABC      10
2     2013/10/11       XYZ      20
3     2013/10/10       PQR      10
4     2013/10/14       MNO      30
5     2013/10/11       UVW      20
```

Now I want result like this:

```
ID    joindate          deptid count(*)
1     2013/09/21         10     2
2     2013/09/22         20     2
4     2013/09/24         30
```

I am using mysql. my table have thousands of record . when i am applying group by it is taking 6-7 second how can i optimize it..

```
select id,latestdate,deptid,count(*) from MyTable 
where joindate>=now()-interval 30 day group by deptid
```

Comment: "my table have thousands of record " - so not very many.

Comment: The general rule is to index the columns that take part in the filtering / comparison (in this case, joindate).

Comment: do you have any indexes on your table?